# Listen To Specific Port With UDPClient & Get Transmitted Packets

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, udpclient

First of all, I apologize for the wrong usage of terminology.

I have a sensor on my local network. It broadcasts current temperature values to everyone on the network on port 35333. I want to create a C# console program that continuously receives packets from this sensor.

This is my current code:

```
public static UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(35333); 

private static async void Start()
{
      Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
}

private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
{
      IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
      byte[] received = Client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

       //Process codes

      Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
}
```

The code above works, however here's the problem: I keep received same byte array all the time.

```
 ...
  [114][51][57][48][48][77][72][112]

  [114][51][57][48][48][77][72][112]

  [114][51][57][48][48][77][72][112]

  [114][51][57][48][48][77][72][112]

  [114][51][57][48][48][77][72][112]
 ...
```

As far as I know, and again, excuse my poor networking knowledge, I must somehow send an acknowledgement back to this sensor, so it starts sending me the ''real'' data.

Any tips or suggestions welcomed!

Comment: UDP is a sessionless broadcast. With a potential for multiple receivers of the UDP packet from this single device, an ACK is highly unlikely. You should review the device protocol docs, as well as see if there is example code available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities here.

First, this may just be the temperature, and it isn't changing. In that case, you need to parse the bytes in the way that the sensor's spec dictates.

Second, if this is indeed the packet that needs an acknowledgement, then you will need to find out which port the sensor listens on (from the spec), and what the acknowledgement packet should look like (from the spec) and send it to that port.

The key here is reviewing the documents that came with the sensor.
New code would sit inside `recv` method and appear similar to the following:

```
private static void recv(IAsyncResult res) 
{ 
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    byte[] received = Client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

    //Pseudo code
    //start_packet is the packet of bytes above from the sensor
    If (received == start_packet)
    {
        //send acknowledgement
    }

    //Process codes
    Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null); 
}
```